# Regular expression is not working on xeditable angular directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) angular directive. I need to use a regex in one of my fields to validate `positive decimal values`. However, it's not working properly. Could you tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Example values include `12,125.25`, etc.

```
<span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" e-pattern="/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/">
                {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
 </span>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9298/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the regex as it does not accept thousand separator now.

Use this regex:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT7jA6/2)

I added:

- `\d{1,3}` - Match 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - Match 0 or more sequences of `,` + 3 digits.

If non-capturing groups do not work for you, remove `?:`.

If you do not want to allow `0`-only input (i.e. the number only consists of `0`s), use

```
^(?![0,.]+$)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT7jA6/4)

Comment: At this moment where I can enter `0` value.Could you tell me how to validate that too ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to disallow `0`-only input? [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/kT7jA6/3)?

Comment: Yes,In other words user cannot enter `0` value.The values should be `> 0`